# When is the Android APK signature verified?

Tags: android, apk, signature

Under which circumstances is the APK signature (contained in /META-INF/CERT.*) verified?

I image the following situations:

1. During installation from Google Play.
2. During installation from adb install.
3. Others?

I am interesting in the actual signature, not only the check of the various digests contained in the files /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and /META-INF/CERT.SF.

Answer (score 0):

The Android apk file signature will be verified while

1.While you are uploading apk file to Google Play Server.
2. During installation from Google Play.

Comment: If the APK signature is not validated during e.g. adb install, does this mean that the signature essentially has been disabled, if the app is installed that way (adb install)? If this is the case, the only way to be sure that the signature is validated is to perform the check programmatically. However it seems (googling), this is a difficult task to acomplish?

Comment: Yes, if u need to check, you need to do it programmatically.

Comment: Avadhani Y, do you have any links or references, which could back up your point that the APK signature is not checked during "adb install" and only during Google Play installation?

If I alter one of the sha-1 digests (I beleave it was in CERT.SF), adb install fails with "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES".

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for signature verification at the time of uploading a app in Google play , then is verification happen at time of uploading your App. for more detail you can go through this link

http://www.xyzmo.com/en/products/Pages/Signature-Verification.aspx

Comment: My concern is, when the Android OS triggers a signature verification. I beleave that the OS verifies the signature, when the user downloads and installs the app from Google Play. I have more doubts if the user installs the APK using adb install. Finally there may be other ways for installing an app, in which case I would like to know, if the signature verification is performed.

Comment: If you find my ans is suitable for question. Then up-vote it.